# basic confusion about vector environment combined with stable baseline model predict

Tags: python, openai-gym, stable-baselines

I’d like to make my basic confusion clear by some demo codes below.

So as usual, when we need to train multiply we use SubprocVecEnv to define env.

but when it comes to load saved model and making the test run, we should still pass a SubprocVecEnv to predict? isn’t that model shall use a single real world input observation and step each once? why codes like these below

```
test_env = DummyVecEnv([make_env(test_provider) for _ in range(1)])

obs, reward, done, info = test_env.step([action[0]])
```

that means even in testing data, we still multi testing?? but there only one test data set,shouldn’t we only need to make single observation for single step? why the vector env in training have business with model testing

even this in loading a model saved just pass a dummyvecenv?? If in the real world environment, we could not pass realtime in several ways could we?

demo code cannot understand

```
init_envs = DummyVecEnv([make_env(test_provider) for _ in range(self.n_envs)])

model_path = path.join('data', 'agents', f'{self.study_name}__{model_epoch}.pkl')
model = self.Model.load(model_path, env=init_envs)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! What have you tried so far? Please provide the code you used and error/questions about it, such that it makes it easier for us to help you!